# How do I start x11vnc via bash script on startup, not login?

Tags: bash, xubuntu, vnc, autostart

I have a server with Xubuntu 11.10 Desktop installed, and x11vnc. When on login screen I want x11vnc to start and to take some settings:

Automatically set defined password

Automatically accept conncetions, but ask for a password

Automatically start this script on loading the system, not the user profile.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can create a script that does the operations you would like to do at startup you can then:
 1. Create the script (e.g. runX11vnc.sh)
 2. Copy the script to /etc/init.d
 3. Run the following commands:
`sudo update-rc.d runX11vnc.sh defaults

sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/runX11vnc.sh`

The script should now run on startup.